# sequence of close and bounded sets in a prefect space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that$(E_n)$$_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of closed and bounded sets in complete space $M$ such that $ E_{n+1} \subseteq  E_n$ for all $ n \in\mathbb N$. If $\lim \operatorname{diam} E_n $= $0$, prove that $E$ contains one point where $E = \bigcap_{n \in\mathbb N} E_n$.
   $(E_n)$ $_{n \in \mathbb N}$ are bounded and closed

Comment: What's a prefect space?

Comment: If any Cauchy (note spelling and capital letter) sequence converges, then the space is complete. Perfect is something else ... unless you insist on using "perfect" ... or "prefect" ... in the above sense in your question. What is _bounded_? Is your space a metric space?

Comment: Yesi changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Pick $x_n\in E_n$. Given any $\varepsilon>0$ use that $\operatorname{diam} E_n\to 0$ to pick $N$ such that $\operatorname{diam} E_N<\varepsilon$. Note that if $n,m>N$ then $x_n,x_m\in E_N$, hence $d(x_n,x_m)<\varepsilon$. Hence the $x_n$ form a Cauchy sequence. Since $M$ is a complete (and you should have stated metric) space, this sequence converges to some $x$. Use that each $E_n$ contains a tail of this sequence and is closed, hence each $E_n$ contains the limit $x$.